# Downgrade Laravel project version?

Tags: php, laravel

I have made a Laravel web application which is working on my localhost with PHP version: 5.6.8, but on the live server PHP version is 5.4.42 and application is giving error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /home/content/p3pnexwpnas04_data02/49/2370249/html/kjhjhkj/nkjkjkk/public/index.php on line 50
```

From what i have read, problem is that latest laravel version needs PHP 5.5 version. So what are my options now ? Should i downgrade laravel version of the project and how? I am able to download Laravel 4.2 version but how to merge it with project that I made already?

Comment: Get a host that has PHP 5.5 or higher. PHP 5.4 is no longer supported and thus **dangerously insecure and irresponsible to run** at this time.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the times, major hosting providers allow to execute multiple versions of PHP and you can pick one of them using the .htaccess file in your public directory, or some settings in your panel.

I'm not aware about the hosting you're using, but you could try something like this: 
http://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/hardware-software/php-5-5

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely can't switch (although it's strongly recommended and usually possible, even with shared hosting), you don't really need to go as low as 4.2. Laravel 5.0 only needs [PHP >= 5.4](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0#server-requirements). Since Laravel 5.1 and 5.0 are mostly identical, you could create a new 5.0 app and copy the contents of your 5.1 app there. Then you should make sure to undo any changes that would of had been done with the upgrade guide below:

> [Upgrade to Laravel 5.1 Guide](http://laravel.com/docs/master/upgrade#upgrade-5.1.0)

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade your Laravel framework version in composer.json file. It is easier than trying to downgrade php version